# Incomple text while saving seaborn figures

Tags: python, seaborn, eda

I have the following data frame:

[image]

For which I'm plotting a varchar using Seaborn:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x='Numero de respuestas', y='Carrera' , 

data=carrera_sum)
fig = ax.set_xlabel('Numero de respuestas')
```

[image]

On the notebook, it looks fine but when I try to save it:

```
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig(join(figuras,'carreras_comunes_latam.png'))
```

I get an incomplete image:

[image]

Comment: It depends on whether you want to shrink the axes, `plt.tight_layout()`. Or whether you want to extent the figure, `fig.savefig(..., bbox_inches="tight")`. There are many questions on that, so please refer to those.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest "bbox_inches="tight"" worked thanks.